# Something like datagrid in Javascript

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I am looking for a way to show data from JSON to my page that looks like table but with limited records size and scroll and I need to update it if data from JSON changes.
It may be simple questions but am new to jQuery.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a plugin i use http://www.datatables.net/. It's quite extendable.

Comment: thank you for reply and i will not forget to thumb up when it work :)

Answer (score 0):

this link have simple way to do this http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/
after setup the table if you want to control the table
1-delete all records

```
var table = document.getElementById("data-table");
            while(table.rows.length > 0) {
            table.deleteRow(0);
            }
```

2-add row

```
$('#data-table').append('<tr> <td>somthing1</td> <td>somthing2</td> <td>somthing3</td></tr>');
```

and that is simply how to do this... dataTables website have more options but more options take longer to understand but better way to work.
this way is classic.